# Access shared view folder in a .net core application running on an azure server

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

While running my site locally, I was accessing files in the shared view folder like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Views/Shared");
```

because I am getting page content dynamically through an API call, and some of the fields have partial views written to override the default rendering. I just grab the shared views name that match some content in the api call, set it in a variable, then use that variable to render the partial view in the .cshtml page.

This works fine locally, but failed after deploying to Azure, but some googling told me that the method I should access project files is using IWebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath. Again, that works fine locally; but after deploying to Azure, the folder structure changes so that the /views/shared folder (or any project folders other than wwwroot) doesn't exist. I *think* azure is just building the project as there is a views.dll file; but now I don't know how to set these filenames into variables in my model.

Is there a way to iterate over my /views/shared folder after deploying?

Comment: Hi @jmrch, any updates about this case? If the answer could help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

> after deploying to Azure, the folder structure changes so that the /views/shared folder (or any project folders other than wwwroot) doesn't exist. I think azure is just building the project as there is a views.dll file; but now I don't know how to set these filenames into variables in my model.

You can try to set `CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory` property to `true`, which would help copy RazorGenerate items (.cshtml) files to the publish directory.

```
<PropertyGroup>

  <!--other properties here-->

  <CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>true</CopyRazorGenerateFilesToPublishDirectory>
  
  <!--other properties here-->

</PropertyGroup>
```

For more information, please check the following doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-5.0#properties

[image]